# Chat keeps saying "I must log in"

Tags: support, bug, chat, login

I cannot get to the chat, I have cleared my cookies and restarted my browser, I click login, it logs me in but whenever I click the chat page it shows me as not logged in.

What should I do?

Comment: As a workaround, try the [ghetto login route.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79724/157951)

Comment: I get a not found even with the example there @BillDubuque

Comment: That used to work for me long ago when I encountered similar problems. Maybe things have changed, or your problem is a bit different.

Comment: @BillDubuque not doing anything worked, suddenly I'm back

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issue was resolved and there does not seem to be a good way to find out why the problem occurred in the first place.